# How can I randomize the images in a twitter bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of images that get loaded for a carousel, and it works great. The issue is that every time the page gets loaded, the carousel starts on the same image.

What's the best way to randomize the starting point, and for extra credit, how can I randomize the image sequence?

Here is a sample setup on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfVTL/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. @codemonkey had the same idea for the random start:

```
$('.item').eq(Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length))).addClass("active");
```

Comment: To also remove the active class: $('.item').removeClass('active').eq(Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length))).addClass("active");

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number (within your range) and set the 'active' attribute on the div item dynamically rather than always setting it to the first item.

To randomise the next image shown, again generate a random number and call `.carousel(number)` to jump to that image.